# Partition Problem

Tags: partitioning

I was hoping to install Ubuntu first day of me getting my laptop but this partition problem stopped me from doing so.

In the first boot it asked if I wanted to partition my hard drives. Didn't know what to do at the time and had to leave so I shut off the computer. When I booted it back up later that night I found I had 3 hard drives. C: is 50GB, System F: 100MB and Temp_Part01 D: 524.90GB. My laptop has 6GB of Ram I believe. I did a system recovery that came with the laptop hoping it'll boot into partition program made by Samsung on the first boot like it did the first time.

Could use some help. Been banging my head trying to figure this out.

Comment: What is your end goal... Dual boot or fix Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Since you list some drives by letters, it's clear you have Windows installed, too.  Since you're evidently setting up a dual-boot configuration, have you decided how much space you want to give to each operating system?  The first thing you ought to do is boot into Windows and look at each of your drives and see what, if anything, is in them.  The C: drive should have Windows, of course, but you need to be sure that there isn't anything on the other drives that you don't want to lose.   (Since you just got your laptop, that's unlikely.)

Once you've made that decision, the best way to handle the partitions is to boot from the Ubuntu "Live" CD, and choose "Try It" instead of "Install".  Once you get to the Ubuntu desktop, open The Dash (the round Ubuntu logo at the top of the Launcer) and type "gp": that will bring up the GParted icon; choose it and let it open.  GParted is used for creating/resizing/deleting partitions.  It's a very good program that can handle lots of different filesystems, including Windows NTFS partitions.

In GParted, the partitions won't be known as C: or F: or any other letters, but will have names like sda1, sda2, sda3, etc.  (If you have additional physical drives, they might be known as sdb, sdc, etc.; the a, b, c, etc. refer to physical drives, the numbers 1, 2, 3, etc., refer to partitions on those drives.)

This picture is of GParted's look at my computer, which doesn't have Windows installed but which has other partitions for other uses, including another version of Ubuntu and some unallocated space I use for testing.[image]

Anyway, if you right click on a partition, you will be shown a menu that gives you the option of resizing or moving or deleting a partition.  Since it's a new laptop, you probably don't have anything installed onto other drives, except Windows in the C: drive; if that's the case, you should probably delete those empty partitions.  This should leave you with one partition (I'm guessing it'll be sda1, the C: drive containing Windows), and a lot of unallocated space.

Once you're at this point, you might want to enlarge the Windows partition.  You can right-click on that partition and choose to resize, but be very careful.  You can expand it as much as you'd like into the unallocated space to the right, but be careful not to "move" the partition to the left; Windows often doesn't like that and it might cause you problems when you try to boot again into Windows.  Also note that when you decide and tell GParted that you want to resize the partition, it won't actually do it until you push the "arrow" button (I think it's the right-most button above the partition window); until then, it's a pending operation.  Resizing the partition might take some time, but that's all right, just let it run until it's done.

Once you have resized Windows to make it as you'd like, you'll still have unallocated space remaining, and that's fine.  If you're happy with the sizes, go ahead and close GParted, and then click on the icon (on the desktop or launcher) to install Ubuntu.  (If you want to create multiple partitions for later use, you can easily go back and make those later; for now, just let Ubuntu use all the remaining space.)  As it proceeds, you'll get to a window in which you'll be given some choices: choose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows; it will automatically put it into the unallocated space (I think it'll let you choose the format of the filesystem to use: I'd recommend using "ext4," which is a Linux filesystem.  (If you're asked for a mountpoint, which I don't think will happen with this type of installation, choose "/"; as I said, though, it probably won't ask.)

At that point, you just need to answer a few questions, such as computer name and such, and let the install proceed.  It will install the Linux bootloader, known as Grub, and eventually finish and tell you it needs to restart.  As it shuts down, it'll kick out the CD (and ask you to press "Enter").  Then it'll reboot, and the Grub window will appear, allowing you to boot into Windows or into Ubuntu.

(If, on the other hand, you're going to wipe Windows from the drive and just install Ubuntu, you should still boot from the "live" CD but choose to install Ubuntu, and when you get to the screen asking where to install it, choose to use the entire drive; it will then wipe off Windows and install Ubuntu.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Been beating myself with that little mess up I made on my new lappy. I just wiped Windows and installed Ubuntu, now just having problem getting it to boot after the install asked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111813/ubuntu-wont-boot-after-install